# Gitosis installation error

Tags: git

I am trying to install gitosis on my server but keep getting the error "Username contains not allowed characters"

`sudo -H -u git gitosis-init < /tmp/id_rsa.pub`

with the username "abhinav@115.118.212.234.static-delhi.vsnl.net.in".

Any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a problem with your 'username' in the id_rsa.pub, open it up, and make the text at the end something like 'alan.pub'